# How to do a scalar product along the right axes with numpy and vectorize the process

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra

I have numpy array 'test' of dimension (100, 100, 16, 16) which gives me a different 16x16 array for points on a 100x100 grid. 
I also have some eigenvalues and vectors where vals has the dimension (100, 100, 16) and vecs (100, 100, 16, 16) where vecs[x, y, :, i] would be the ith eigenvector of the matrix at the point (x, y) corresponding to the ith eigenvalue vals[x, y, i].

Now I want to take the first eigenvector of the array at ALL points on the grid, do a matrix product with the test matrix and then do a scalar product of the resulting vector with all the other eigenvectors of the array at all points on the grid and sum them. 
The resulting array should have the dimension (100, 100). After this I would like to take the 2nd eigenvector of the array, matrix multiply it with test and then take the scalar product of the result with all the eigenvectors that is not the 2nd and so on so that in the end I have 16 (100, 100) or rather a (100, 100, 16) array. I only succeded sofar with a lot of for loops which I would like to avoid, but using tensordot gives me the wrong dimension and I don't see how to pick the axis which is vectorized along for the np.dot function. 
I heard that einsum might be suitable to this task, but everything that doesn't rely on the python loops is fine by me.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as la

test = np.arange(16*16*100*100).reshape((100, 100, 16, 16))
vals, vecs = la.eig(test + 1)

np.tensordot(vecs, test, axes=[2, 3]).shape
>>> (10, 10, 16, 10, 10, 16)
```

EDIT: Ok, so I used np.einsum to get a correct intermediate result.

```
np.einsum('ijkl, ijkm -> ijlm', vecs, test)
```

But in the next step I want to do the scalarproduct only with all the other entries of vec. Can I implement maybe some inverse Kronecker delta in this einsum formalism? Or should I switch back to the usual numpy now?

Comment: Use `np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ij',vecs,test)` to get the matrix products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I played around and with np.einsum I found a way to do what is described above. A nice feature of einsum is that if you repeat doubly occuring indices in the 'output' (so right of the '->'-thing) you can have element-wise multiplication along some and contraction along some other axes (something that you don't have in handwritten tensor algebra notation).

```
result =  np.einsum('ijkl, ijlm -> ijkm', np.einsum('ijkl, ijkm -> ijlm', vecs, test), vecs)
```

This nearly does the trick. Now only the diagonal terms have to be taken out. We could do this by just substracting the diagonal terms like this:

```
result = result - result * np.eye(np.shape(test)[-1])[None, None, ...]
```